# Core Plot ios animate scatter plot from plain, straight line to plot with actual data

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, core-plot, scatter-plot

I've been using Core Plot for my iPhone application and have been displaying a scatter plot. I was wondering if upon appearance of the view, there is anyway to have the scatter plot start off as just a horizontal line with all y-values the same, and then have some sort of 0.5 second, for example, animation that slowly moves each data point up or down to its appropriate position?? *Or, more generally, if the scatter plot can be animated in any way using core plot?* Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing like that built in at the moment. Each plot is drawn in its own `CALayer` which can be animated like any other layer. For example, you can slide it into place or fade it into view.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured. I just have it slide into the view. Thank you for your response!